# How to send UDP requests via asyncio in python 3

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, influxdb, influxdb-python

I would like to send UDP messages to my InfluxDB server using asyncio. This is my synchronous code:

```
import socket
import requests
from logger import get_logger

log = get_logger(__name__)


class InfluxDB(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password, host, port, udp=True, udp_port=4444):
        log.info("InfluxDBClient()")
        self.udp = udp
        if self.udp:
            self.udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            self.udp_port_tuple = (host, udp_port)
        self.session = requests.session()
        self.session.auth = (username, password)
        self.base_url = "http://{}:{}".format(host, port)

    def _query(self, payload, endpoint="/query"):
        log.debug(payload)
        return self.session.post(self.base_url + endpoint, params=payload)

    def _write(self, db, data, endpoint="/write"):
        log.debug("{} \t {}".format(db, data))
        return self.session.post(self.base_url + endpoint, params={"db": db}, data=data)

    def write_udp(self, data_str):
        if self.udp:
            return self.udp_socket.sendto(data_str.encode("utf-8"), self.udp_port_tuple)
        else:
            raise Exception("UDP disabled")
```

How do I rewrite the "write_udp" function using the async/await syntax?

-- edit 7/5/2018 --

To be more specific, I am unsure how to reference the asyncio equivalent of "socket". Presumably there is a version of an asyncio based socket, which I would reference as self.udp_socket = socket.socket_asyncio, and then I would fire off messages via await socket.socket_asyncio.sendto(....) what I need to understand is how to reference this asyncio based socket object.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem(s) are you having?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori that's synchronous

Comment: @dirn I am not sure how to reference the asyncio equivalent of "socket".

Comment: Are [streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: @dirn I thought streams were only for TCP not UDP?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe [transports and protocols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html) would be a better fit.